# Configuring Docker daemon for GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, github-actions

I learned from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/732720/413026) that Docker does not by default support IPv6 and that `/etc/docker/daemon.json` has to be edited to change that.

I have a GitHub Action which operates inside of a Docker container.  I.e.,

```yaml
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: my/image:sometag
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: make tests
```

For this action, I'm running a test that binds to a non-privileged port on `::1`.  Is there something I can put in my YAML file to configure the Docker daemon to allow IPv6?

[This closed issue](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/668) might be relevant.  However, in that case, the user was trying to access the internet via IPv6.  I just need to use the loopback interface.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://github.com/docker/docs/issues/6075.

Comment: @RichardRublev, unless I'm missing something, that just explains how to configure the daemon.  What I need to know is how to get GitHub Actions to configure the daemon.